# Ant compile is not creating build directory

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Environment: Mac OSX 10.7.5, Eclipse 4.2.1, Apache Ant version 1.8.2

I created a sample Hello World program in Eclipse then exported the project into a build.xml file.

At the prompt i type in:

$ant

> Buildfile: /Users/cspam/Documents/workspace/TestHelloWorld/build.xml
>
> build-subprojects:
>
> init:
>
> build-project:
>        [echo] TestHelloWorld: /Users/cspam/Documents/workspace/TestHelloWorld/build.xml
>
> build:
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL

but the build directory that i am looking for is not created. Here is my xml file:

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="TestHelloWorld">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../eclipse"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.6"/>
<property name="source" value="1.6"/>
<path id="TestHelloWorld.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target name="cleanall" depends="clean"/>
<target name="build" depends="build-subprojects,build-project"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target name="build-project" depends="init">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="TestHelloWorld.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target name="build-refprojects" description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes."/>
<target name="init-eclipse-compiler" description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target name="build-eclipse-compiler" description="compile project with Eclipse compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
```

I am new to using Ant - so this is all new to me. I was told that it should build a "Build" directory but it is not created. I am not sure what I am doing so would appreciate any pointers/help/suggestions.

UPDATE: as @Cliff suggested. here is the output for ant after doing ant -clean

> Buildfile: /Users/cspam/Documents/workspace/TestHelloWorld/build.xml
>
> build-subprojects:
>
> init:
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/cspam/Documents/workspace/TestHelloWorld/bin
>
> build-project:
>        [echo] TestHelloWorld: /Users/cspam/Documents/workspace/TestHelloWorld/build.xml
>       [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/cspam/Documents/workspace/TestHelloWorld/bin
>
> build:
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 0 seconds

looks like the .class files were indeed created after a clean. Right clicking the "build.xml" file from within Eclipse and doing Run As->Ant Build will also do the same successfully.

I am in the process of now pushing this xml file off to Bamboo to see if i can get a clean run. Is this a straight forward process? thanks again for help.

Comment: Please have the "name" attribute be the *first* attribute in each target, since it's the most important; we can't even see the target names without scrolling.

Comment: Unless using the Eclipse build automatically creates a build directory, I don't see anything here that creates the dir. Where are the classes actually ending up?

Comment: @DaveNewton This... looks like a build file created by some IDE (eclipse) automatically so the `name` attribute is not first. Same with Netbeans, which puts `depends` first...

Comment: `javac` task seems to output the class file to `./bin`, and this directory is made in target `init`. Do u have that directory in your project folder after the build?

Comment: @DaveNewton i swapped the name and depends order so that the name is now first but still no directories are created.

Comment: @coolcfan yes - this was built with Eclipse. Project Properties->Export->General Tab->Ant Buildfiles. my java source file are under the src directory and under the bin directory are the .class files(in this case TestHelloWorld.class). However no ant directories(build..etc) are built - even after swapping the order of the "name" and "depends". It still says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" however.

Comment: The ordering is so we can read it, it has nothing to do with build mechanics.

Comment: ok so i have reordered them for you - just updated it..

Comment: As mentioned above, your build.xml is coded to create a "bin" folder not a "build" folder. Does the "bin" folder exist before and after you run it? Run ant with -v for verbose output or -d for even more debug info to see exactly what each task is doing.

Comment: it looks like it does create the bin folder and the .class files when cleaned out. added some output for verification. thanks for the info.